# Should we rephrase our off-topic reason 1 to read "on humanities and social sciences" instead of just "social sciences"

Tags: feature-request

Our off-topic closure, reason 1, is "Questions on social sciences other than History are off-topic here, unless they also involve history in some fashion. While ethics, archaeology, etc. are all connected to history, each field has their own experts who are better equipped to answer such questions."

Should we rephrase this to read "Questions on humanities and social sciences other than History are off-topic here, unless they also involve history in some fashion. While ethics, archaeology, etc. are all connected to history, each field has their own experts who are better equipped to answer such questions."

?

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  We should rephrase off-topic closure reason 1.  History is not just a social science, but also a humanity, and we regularly get questions on humanities other than history, not just social sciences other than history.